# Register variable in port declaration in verilog

Tags: verilog

I want to make a module in Verilog which must get a 32 bit wide register variable in port. This variable will be used to count the clock cycle. Then this module will be instantiated in another module. For example: when I fix the value of counter this module must start count from that value.

When I simulate this code I get an error:

> Non-net port count cannot be of mode input

```
module case_1( input clk , input [31:0] counter);
  reg [31:0] counter;

  always @ (posedge clk)
    begin
      counter <=counter +1
    end

endmodule

module counter (input clk , input [31:0] counter )
  reg [31:0] counter;
  case_1 h1  ( .clk(clk) , .counter(counter) )
endmodule
```

Comment: You defined `counter` as an `input` signal and a register at the same moment. This is not possible.

Comment: but how i can do this.. please can you correct this

Comment: in `case_1` you have counter as an input, then drive a value onto it. If your driving the value should it not be an output?

Answer (score 2):

If a module is an input then you can not drive a value on to it. Driving a value on to an input does not make sense. It needs to be an output.

It think there might be some confusion over the `reg` and `wire` types in verilog. These types do not cross module interfaces. a lower (sub) module drives its output as a reg type. the next level up a wire is connected to the port.

From your example a clock received by counter which uses sub module case_1 to implement the counter. Counter value is then driven (first as a reg) then at the top level as a wire.

```
module case_1( 
  input clk ,
  output reg [31:0] counter
);

  initial begin
    counter = 'b0;
  end

  always @ (posedge clk) begin
    counter <=counter +1;
  end

endmodule

module counter (input clk , output wire [31:0] counter );
  case_1 h1  ( .clk(clk) , . counter(counter) );
endmodule
```

Example on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/GxA).